# Настройка OpenVPN + ГОСТ

Tags: криптография, openvpn

Возможно ли в качестве алгоритма шифрования использовать ГОСТ 28147-89 при настройке OpenVPN в CentOS 6?

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли. ГОСТ 28147-89 - это симметричный алгоритм, а для VPN нужен асимметричный алгоритм.